# Stop receiving real time updates without an access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to stop receiving real time updates for 1 specific page for my Facebook application, I have no user access token for the user or the page.

In this scenario, is there anyway to stop receiving real time updates from the page 
without having to actually contact the page owner and ask them to remove the application tab from the page.

I have tried issuing a `DELETE` request to the `/<page_id>/tabs/app_<app_id>` route but off-course this isn't working because you need an access_token for this. 
I also tried using an application token instead ( which I thought might have worked, but unfortunately it didn't. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been made possible by Facebook after a bug report.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1496164130596487/

This is the edge you will want to delete:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/tabs#delete

All tough the latest docs ( 2.1 ) still state that you need a page access_token, you should now be able to do it with an app access_token as well.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO and according to the docs, you just need an App Access Token to stop the realtime updates:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/subscriptions/#deleteperms

```
DELETE /{app-id}/subscriptions
```

with

```
object=page
```

as body.

Comment: The problem with that is that it stops **all** real time updates. If i re-enable the real time updates after disabling it like this I will still receive updates from the unwanted pages.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you want to stop *all* realtime updates. I think the only option would be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/tabs/#delete but if you don't have the Page Access Token, this seems to be impossible...